Call to REST WS Fails with javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch but succeeds in curl and Postman
I am calling a GET JSON REST web service from a J2EE 10 application running on Payara 6 that works fine with curl (from the same instance) and postman (from home PC) and also works fine and consistently inside the exact same application (via the same ami) from a different AWS VPC. But it fails every time on the production server implementation.
It works intermittently from my home computer - no idea why it works sometimes and not others. Postman from home computer works every time.
Here's the error:
jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:270)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:300)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$1(JerseyInvocation.java:675)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.call(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$runInScope$3(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.runInScope(JerseyInvocation.java:691)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:674)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:318)
    at com.tm2builder.careeronestop.CosBuilder.getOccupationJsonResponse(CosBuilder.java:696)
    at com.tm2builder.careeronestop.CosUtils.processGetOccupationData(CosUtils.java:236)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.glassfish.expressly.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.expressly.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.expressly.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:248)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:70)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.getNavigationOutcome(ActionListenerImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:62)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:205)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:858)
    at jakarta.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1332)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:56)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:72)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:159)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:691)
    at jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:449)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1554)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
    at com.tm2builder.util.SetEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetEncodingFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:239)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:123)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:586)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1599)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:531)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:307)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:268)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode$GCMDecrypt.doFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:1652)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.engineDoFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:458)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2543)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T13GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1908)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    ... 76 more

Here's the curl without the API Key:
 curl --location 'https://api.careeronestop.org/v1/occupation/KTlBjGthMe8nDlZ/11-1011.00/0?wages=true&projectedEmployment=true&videos=true' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer *********'

curl - Works every time from all instances and home PC.
postman - Works every time from home PC (windows).
Java app - Works every time from an instance in an AWS VPC (Amazon Linux 2023)

Fails every time from an instance in a different AWS VPC, even when I use an ami created from the instance where it works every time. But curl works every time from this instance.  (Amazon Linux 2023)
Works sometimes from the same app on my PC.

Since it works in curl every time from the same instance, I don't think it's a network issue.
When it works, the web service returns well-formed JSON.
I've tried everything I can think of, from every possible method of calling the GET using Jersey (above), httpclient, httpclient5, always with the same results.
I've tried JDK 21 (above), 22, and 17. No change. Have done a complete re-install of Payara, and using completely new instances of AL 2023, and the apps - no change.
I've inspected the java security policy and see no differences between the working and non-working instances.
The AWS Security Groups involved are completely open for HTTPS 443 Outbound traffic.
The Network ACLs involved allow all outbound and inbound traffic.
The Java code to make the call (using Jersey) is very simple:
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(uri);
JsonObject response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header( HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + COS_API_KEY ).get(JsonObject.class);

I've also tried Apache httpclient and httpclient5 with the exact same results.

I was able to prevent this error by restricting this web service to only use TLS 1.2 on apache httpclient5. This took a few iterations before TLS 1.3 was disabled. What seems to have done the trick was using an SSLConnectionSocketFactory
